# After upgrading Console Firebase.Server.timestamp in IOS Will return Wrong Values (SDK 2.5.1)

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi i upgraded the Console to latest version but my app still using the sdk 2.5.1
now when i try to send timestamp ( in ios im sending the dictionary [".sv":"timestamp"]  )  after the console upgrade now i have this saved

`{"nativeStorage":{"initializedEntries":{"bitCount":2,"values":{"pointerValue":2036426880}},"keys":{"pointerValue":2036426904},"values":{"pointerValue":2036426928}}}`

it worked correctly before the console upgrade

Comment: The values stored should be the same (after upgrading to the new console your code is still talking to the same database server). Can you show the minimal code that allows me to reproduce this problem?

Comment: My mistake sorry... it was a problem of swift evreflection sdk ( problem with converting Dictionary to NSDictionary)

Comment: Good to hear. I'll vote to close, because this will just confuse people.